# Is this allowed?

Tags: support, site-promotion

I am a member of this website and need to ask a favor. I have a small publishing company I've started specializing in quality inexpensive mathematics textbooks at the university level, both reprints and original works. Many of my target client base will be on this message board. Would I be allowed to write posts describing my published books with links to them? I don't want to do anything that's going to get me banned from the site,so I wanted to ask first.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you for asking. I am sorry but this is not admissible. You would run a serious risk of the posts being perceived and treated as spam.

To show just how serious this risk is note that you mentioning one of your products in an answer already did raise some eye-brows. To me it stayed below the threshold of being a misuse so I did not take any action, but you really should not go further than that.

The general SE rule is this (as far as I know and recall, I might look up an official source later). A user is allowed to mention their own products and services as long as

- it comes up naturally, occasionally,  and actually provides pertinent information,
- it is disclosed that they promote their own product.

I felt the answer I mentioned above fulfilled that, so it was alright. But that is about the limit of what is tolerated.

Comment: Here is [the Help Center on "Promotion" (a.k.a. How to not be a spammer)](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)

Comment: Thanks, for providing this link. I did not recall it was in the help-center.